# how to set background image of an imageButton from java file

Tags: java, android-studio, android-imagebutton, setbackground

i already have a imagebutton with a background. When i click the Imagebutton, i want the background to change to another image. I tried using "//.setBackgroundResourse", but it didnt change anything. Please help

Comment: Please show some code :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a drawable argument in your `setBackgroundResource`

Like this:

```
Button myButton = (Button) View.findViewById(R.id.myButton);

myButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.myBackground);
```